# API not returning anything near the actual website

Tags: bug, support, status-completed, api

The API /questions page is not returning anything like the list of questions on the actual SO site.

This is the first question of the 0.8/questions

```
{
  "total": 705769,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "questions": [
    {
      "tags": [
        ".net",
        "file",
        ".net-4.0",
        "c#4.0",
        "enumeration"
      ],
      "answer_count": 1,
      "favorite_count": 3,
      "question_timeline_url": "/questions/2663574/timeline",
      "question_comments_url": "/questions/2663574/comments",
      "question_answers_url": "/questions/2663574/answers",
      "question_id": 2663574,
      "owner": {
        "user_id": 44952,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "display_name": "codymanix",
        "reputation": 2956,
        "email_hash": "ef35431926e50a1f953e88d22a32b936"
      },
      "creation_date": 1271618253,
      "last_edit_date": 1275470990,
      "last_activity_date": 1275470990,
      "up_vote_count": 10,
      "down_vote_count": 0,
      "view_count": 131,
      "score": 10,
      "community_owned": false,
      "title": "Strange thing about .NET 4.0 filesystem enumeration functionality"
    },
```

As you can see the title is 'Strange thing about .NET 4.0 filesystem enumeration functionality`

The first question on just SO.com is:

[image: https://i200.photobucket.com/albums/aa230/warriorST/CMCapture16.png]

And the `Strange thing about .NET 4.0 filesystem enumeration functionality` question is the 23rd question for the top on the SO.com page.

It gets stranger as the second question from the API page is actually before (closer to the top of the page) the first API question on the SO.com page. So the questions seem completely out of order.

This was fine yesterday, but I've also noticed the answers were removed (thanks :)) so it means there have been changes to the API.

Comment: If answers are removed, I need to do bug report again. Returning answers altogether save me for daily rate-limit, but not returning Answers save you bandwidth, so we definitely need `answer=true/false`

Comment: Yes, there are some cases where I can see it'd be useful to have answer=true/false. So I'm seconding that.

Comment: This looks like a consequence of some cache optimizations that recently went out.  It will be improved/fixed in the near future, thought the site and api will always run the risk of being out of sync to some degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at 'questions' and not the landing page?

Seems not.

The landing page reflect's activity, not timeline.

Click on 'questions' to get what you are looking for.

Comment: landing page is same as sort=active, IMHO, http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=active  and it was working before, IIRC

Comment: Oh I forgot to add I had also checked the API against the questions page and it didn't match up either. yesterday I was just looking at the main SO page and it matched the API, but today it doesn't.
According to the API documentation sort=active is the default on the /0.8/questions.

Comment: @Smark - i think we are saying the same thing - active does not represent the insertion order of questions which is what OP is/was after or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Adding dummy parameter `min=-1000` give me correct results (also with answers :D), you could use it as work-around at the moment. But definitely this should be fixed.

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?min=-1000&type=jsontext

Comment: Thanks! That produces the right stuff :)
Though they should consider building SO on the API as the API seems faster than the SO site itself :D

Comment: Oh yeah, sometimes few questions ahead of real site. :-)